# Triggering StackNavigator navigation programmatically?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have StackNavigator, which works fine. But I would like to navigate to ScreenB programmatically, without user clicking on the tab, eg. using code like this:

```
const ScreenNavigator = StackNavigator({
    A: { screen: ScreenA, },
    B: { screen: ScreenB, },
});
// There is no "navigate" method in StackNavigator
ScreenNavigator.navigate('B', { "foo": "bar" });
```

Is this possible?

It would be best, if I can navigate to ScreenB so that the ScreenA is also in the stack, that is, pressing 'back' while on ScreenB goes to ScreenA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("B", {"foo":"bar"})
```

in SceneA whenever you want to go to SceneB

Comment: Thanks! I had to add also in ScreenA's constructor a row like this.handleURL = this.handleURL.bind(this), becouse I want to call the navigate function from callback function. But now it work!